# Object Property MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid

I am trying to make a reusable grid that will have a selection tick box and then any number of columns based on the item I send through.

I currently have the display working by using a class that has a bool for the selection and an object for the item to display.

When I am sending the update through to set if the item is selected the item property comes through as {object} (when looked at in the debugger in VS) 
Is it possible to Cast/serialize this into an object I can use?

I am using a Telerik Kendo Grid and Datasource, the Id and the IsSelected are populated fine but Item is not.

Thanks

The Select item view model

```
public class SelectOptionViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public object Item { get; set; }
}
```

The controller method being called

```
public ActionResult UpdateSelectionItem([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,SelectOptionViewModel selectOptions, int sessionId)
{

}
```

The grid on the view

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                autoSync: true,
                transport: {
                    read:  {
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetSelectionItem", "MultiSelect", new { sessionId = Model.SessionId })",
                        type: "post"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("UpdateSelectionItem", "MultiSelect", new { sessionId = Model.SessionId })",
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        type: "post",
                        dataType: 'json'
                    },
                    parameterMap: function(data, type) {
                        return kendo.stringify(data);
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
                    type: "GET"
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "Data",
                    total: "Total",
                    errors: "Errors",
                    model: { id: "Id" }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true
            }),
            navigatable: true,
            columns : GetColumns(),
            height: 550,
            pageable: {
                pageSize: 2
            },
            sortable: {
                mode: "multiple",
                allowUnsort: true
            },
            filterable : true,
            pageable: {
                buttonCount: 5
            }
        }).on('click', '.chkbx', function () {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            var grid = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid;
            grid.closeCell();
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
            var col = $(this).closest('td');
            grid.editCell(col);
            dataItem.set(grid.columns[col.index()].field, checked);
            grid.closeCell(col);
        });

function GetColumns()
{
    var columnList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Columns))
    return columnList;
}
```

Header on update request:

```
{"Id":"1001","IsSelected":true,"Item":{"Code":"1001","Description":"Desc"}}
```

Comment: show code for `GetColumns()`

Comment: Added it to the bottom of the grid, this just allows me to send the column information in, to dynamically add the columns for the item

Comment: well `column.field` shoud be "Item.Code" and "Item.Description"

Comment: yes this bit works fine, The grid displays fine and I can click on the check box and it will call the update method, but when I debug into the method the Item property sent as part of the SelectOptionViewModel that has been edited is {object}. as you can see by the update request all properties are sent as part of the request and you can see that Item is set to have a property of Code and Description

Comment: you can replace `public object Item { get; set; }` with `public SomeClass Item { get; set; }` and then declare `class SomeClass { public string Code { get; set; } public string Description { get; set; } }`

Comment: we have about 20 different description classes I'm trying to make it so I don't need to create a new class / method if a new description is added. Using an object would allow me to have a switch to load / update based on a type property